# scale translate function with python decorator

Tags: python, python-decorators

I have a list of single parameter functions in python to which I would like to apply the same scaling/translation operation.

The scale/translation for a function f(x) would be as follows:

f'(x, a, b, c, d) = a + b* f( c*(x - d) )

So for example if my original function is defined as:

f(x) = 3*x

I would like to modify it to be:

f'(x, a, b, c, d) = a + b * (3*(c*(x - d)))

Ideally using a decorator (or some other reusable operation that I can apply to each function in the list).

Is there a pythonic way to achieve this such that every transformation doesn't need to be hardcoded for each function I have?

Apologies if the question is unclear - thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def f(x):
    return 3*x

def makeFPrime(func):
    def inner(x, a, b, c, d):
        return a + b * (3*(c*func(x-d)))
    return inner
```

This gives for example:

```
f2 = makeFPrime(f)
f2(2,1,1,1,2)
1
f2(2,1,1,1,0)
19
```

Alternatively, use `makeFPrime` as a decorator:

```
def makeFPrime(func):
    def inner(x, a, b, c, d):
        return a + b * (3*(c*func(x-d)))
    return inner

@makeFPrime
def f(x):
    return 3*x
```

Then f(2,1,1,1,2) returns 1